# pip -e: No magic underscore to dash replacement

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

Somewhere underscores get changed to dashes, if you install with a git repo with "pip install -e ...".

Is there any way to stop this?

I want to automate stuff. I want repo `foo_bar` to be `~/src/foo_bar`, not `~/src/foo-bar`.

Comment: It also does it when you package using `python setup.py sdist`: in the resulting `PKG-INFO` file, the package name will be translated from `foo_bar` to `foo-bar`.  Once installed using pip, it will appear with the `-` in the list of your installed packages.

Comment: This is one of the lamest things in python in my opinion. forcing some run no naming convention for modules when underscores are fine in python imports and thus modules but not in the build tools.  Completely lame.

Answer (score 20):

From what I can see from [this question](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2011-August/017935.html) and [this response](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2011-August/017936.html) on the Python mailing list it looks like this is due to numerous naming conventions throughout the Python packaging system, and the compatibility between them.

Pythons `setuptools` runs [`safe_name`](http://nullege.com/codes/search/setuptools.package_index.safe_name) which:

> Convert an arbitrary string to a standard distribution name
>
> Any runs of non-alphanumeric/. characters are replaced with a single '-'.

Even though `pip`, `easy_install` and `PyPi` may accept the underscore, when installing it is changed to a single '-' for setuptools standards.

Comment: It's nice to know that there is a mechanism that replaces it, but the question was, how to stop it. Is there a way to stop the automatic replacement?

Comment: @AlexanderPacha How to fix it? Stop using `setuptools`.  Use a more modern build and packaging tool like [`flit`](https://flit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Why not simply fix setuptools itself?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the answer above is incorrect. The exact regex from the code is `re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9.]+', '-', name)`. But if you try `pip install foo!bar` you get a big parse error so this isn't really true either.

Comment: On the shell the `!` sign is special. If I write `pip install foo!bar` on the shell, I get: `bash: !bar: event not found`. But this all does not matter, since AFAIK no package uses a name like this :-)

Comment: @guettli depends on shell :P