# List packages (with respective versions) installed in a virtualenv without using pip

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

**Context:** After updating from Debian 8 to 9, Python 3.4 virtualenvs stopped working because system site-packages were all replaced by the Python 3.5 version. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39097003/4352108) suggests removing the old virtualenv, creating a new one, and reinstalling all packages using `pip install -r requirements.txt`. **However**, I don't have a `requirements.txt` for all virtualenv. I know that such file can be created with `pip freeze`, but for the reason stated above, `pip` won't work<sup>1</sup>.

**Problem:** I need to generate a list of the packages and their respective installed in a virtualenv that I cannot activate.

**Question:** Is there a way to get a list similar to the output of `pip freeze` for a virtualenv without actually running pip?

**Note:** This question is different from “[Return a list of imported Python modules used in a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572582/return-a-list-of-imported-python-modules-used-in-a-script)” and because the requested answers should not need to access the scripts that use the virtualenv, and should also return the versions of the packages installed in the virtualenv<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Namely, running `pip` (with any parameters) raises `ImportError: No module named 'encodings'`.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Full disclosure: I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51708306/4352108) that was wrongly closed as duplicate.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting the list of installed packages without a working pip will be very hard. Alternatively, you can try making sense from the filenames installed in your virtualenv `site-packages` directory:

You can get the `site-packages` directory by running

```
python -m site
```

and looking for a string like

```
'/your/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages'
```

Take that path and run

```
ls -d /your/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/*.dist-info
```

This should give you a list of the majority of the installed package directories in your virtualenv.

To clean up this list and create a `requirements.txt` file that somewhat resembles the correct syntax and data, you can use

```
ls -d /your/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/*.dist-info | xargs -I% basename % | sed 's/\.dist-info//; s/-/==/; s/_/-/' > requirements.txt
```

Needless to say, you probably need to clean up its contents a little bit afterwards.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Indeed, the output still needs cleaning. For instance, a package named `some-package` would be store in the directory `some_package-version.dist-info` (note that the dash has become an underscore). But this can be done manually.

Comment: Didn't know about the `site` module, very useful. I've been having people open up their REPL and print `sys.path` for me to help debug environment issues...now I know a better way thanks to this answer!

Comment: I have added another `sed` command that replaces `_` with `-` to the pipeline. However there probably are packages that actually contain an underscore.

Comment: It seems that `pip` replaces `_` with `-`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19131777/4352108, so this whole thing should not be a problem anyway. :)