# How to search and import a Python package with importlib that was installed with setuptools and has an underscore in its name

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a Python package with setuptools that has an underscore in its name. The underscore is, according to some naming rules, [replaced by dashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097057/pip-e-no-magic-underscore-to-dash-replacement).

I don't mind so much about the naming, but I cannot automatically import the package, because
pkg_resources.working_set is only giving the name with dashes and not underscores.

```
foo_bar
├─ foo_bar
|  ├─ __init__.py
|  ├─ foo_bar.py
└─ setup.py

python3 setup.py develop --user
```

Listing the pip packages shows that foo_bar is replaced by foo-bar:

```
pip3 list | grep foo
foo-bar                      0.1                       /home/XYZ/foo_bar
```

My problems start if I want to search through all imported modules and import foo_bar again:

```
import pkg_resources
import importlib


for d in pkg_resources.working_set:
    if('foo' in d.project_name):
        print(d.location, d.project_name, d.version, d.key)
        libstr = d.key
        print('Importing lib',libstr)
        testlib = importlib.import_module(libstr)


/home/XYZ/foo_bar foo-bar 0.1 foo-bar
Importing lib foo-bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/XYZ/foo_bar/test/import_foo_bar.py", line 10, in <module>
    testlib = importlib.import_module(libstr)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo-bar'
```

Any ideas how to find the "proper" name? A manual import works:

```
In [1]: import foo_bar

In [2]: foo_bar.foo_bar
Out[2]: <module 'foo_bar.foo_bar' from '/home/XYZ/foo_bar/foo_bar/foo_bar.py'>
```