# Setuptools with dash or underscore

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

My question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097057/pip-e-no-magic-underscore-to-dash-replacement) but I'm hoping for an updated answer for 2023. My project name originally contained a '-' (e.g., abc-def) and I've received a warning that '-' is becoming deprecated in setuptools, similar to [this warning](https://github.com/pyscaffold/pyscaffold/issues/418). So I've renamed my project to use '_' (e.g., abc_def) instead of dash, only to find that `pip install -e .` automatically converts my underscore back to dash (e.g., it builds/installs abc-def-0.1.0-py310.whl). So should we be using dash or underscores when building python packages?

Comment: You have renamed it *where/how* and `pip install -e` turns what exactly back to a dash *where*?

Comment: @deceze Added some examples to show what it's doing.

Comment: The answer to my own question seems to be that it doesn't matter. https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#name